# Google Sheets Error - “Please use desktop to connect this sheet”. Possible due to use of query or import range formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-visualization

I am using a combination of query and import range in a single cell to pull data from another sheet which contains my google form responses. I have allowed access to connect the sheet earlier, during the creation of the formula, using desktop and have no issues drawing the data that I need or creating charts with it.

However after trying to open the google sheets on my mobile and iPad, there is a #REF error in the query/importrange cell, stating “Please use a desktop web browser to connect this sheet”. I am also unable to view the charts after inserting in Google Slides, even though it looks fine in Google Sheets. The charts are blank with no data, stating “Add a series to start visualising your data”.

[REF ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhTqA.jpg)

[GOOGLE CHART ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8U4Ai.jpg)